# Test to see if installed and if not, install it

Tags: bash, linux, shell

Okay all you Linux/shell folks out there. This is my first shell script (2nd if you count "Hello World") and would appreciate some feedback.

Basically, I need to test whether `htop` is installed; if it is, then move on; if it is not, then install it. If the user is root then just do it, and if not, sudo and install it. I have "borrowed" code from here to stitch this together. It works in my test environment. I would like to know:

What did I miss? What other variables do I need to account for? Are there better ways to go about this?

```
if ! [ -x "$(command -v htop)" ]; then
    # set the var SUDO to "" (blank)
    SUDO=""
        # if the user ID is not 0 (root is 0)
        if [ $EUID != "0" ] ; then
        # set the var SUDO to "sudo"
        SUDO="sudo"
        fi
    # Let the user know it is not installed & then install it, using sudo if not root
    echo 'Error: htop is not installed.' && $SUDO apt install htop >&1
    # exit the script
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: It's probably better, from a principle-of-least-surprise standpoint, to simply fail with an error message telling the user what to run, rather than running it for them. It's somewhat invasive to invoke `sudo` for a user if they haven't explicitly granted it (by running the script via `sudo` in the first place), and it's possible the user would prefer a different installation mechanism, such as compiling from source.

Answer (score 8):

Overall it's fine. My suggestions would be:

1. Fix the indenting.
2. If you find the comments helpful, great. Otherwise, consider saying "why" and not "what", e.g. `# set the var SUDO to "" (blank)` -> `# This will be used as a prefix to run a command as root`
3. You can alternatively consider checking if the command exists by running it: `if htop --version > /dev/null 2>&1`. This does not discriminate against aliases, functions and builtins.
4. Prefer user lowercase variable names to avoid conflicting with existing environment variables. `SUDO="sudo"` is ok since `SUDO` isn't in use, but if you had tried the same with `PWD="pwd"` or `SHELL="sh"` you could have gotten some odd side effects.
5. Use `echo 'Error: htop is not installed.' >&2` to write the error message to stderr
6. The `>&1` aka `1>&1` is redundant: it just redirects the FD to where it's already going.
7. It's generally considered rude to install packages without asking the user. A more canonical approach is to simply exit with an error saying that `htop` is missing and leave it to the user to install it (this also avoids tying the script to Ubuntu/Mint).
8. If you continue when `htop` exists, why is the script exiting after installing `htop`? If it's to handle installation failures due to bad password or full disk, you should probably handle that explicitly.
9. You can use `exit` aka `exit $?` to exit with the status of the previous command, so that if the installation failed, you don't claim that the script ran successfully.

Comment: Thank you.  1. Got it. 2. Its just there for me as i learn - so i can go back and remember what i was doing.  But point taken. Thanks. 3. Got it. 4. good point.  thanks. 5. Got it. 6. Got it. 7. This is purely for me, but i understand and appreciate the feedback. 8. That is really all i was trying to do in this script. 9. Got it.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the excellent [answer by that other guy](/a/237656/75307):

1. It's a good idea to start the script with a *shebang* specifying which interpreter to run.  In this case, we're not using any Bash features not present in standard POSIX shell, so we can write

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ```
2. Consider setting the flags `-u` (using unset variables is an error) and `-e` (exit when commands fail and are not otherwise tested):

   ```
   set -eu
   ```
3. It's unusual to follow `echo` with `&&` - we're not depending on its success, so just use `;`.
4. Don't exit with status 0 (success) when `apt` fails.  The easy way to return its exit value is to replace the shell process using `exec`, like this:

   ```
   exec $SUDO apt install htop
   # this line not reached
   ```

Comment: Thank you. 
1. yes i just left that out when i pasted it in.  
2. I need to dig in to this and i am not sure i understand. 
3. Got it. 
4. Got it.

Comment: For item 2, obviously read the manual, but also look at [BashFAQ/105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for some pitfalls.  Some argue that the pitfalls make `set -e` useless; I disagree, but add that it needs to be well understood to be effective and useful.